# edit window is going back in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am working in extjs and have made a grid of records in this. On top of it, there is button edit

record. On click this button,  edit window is going back and not able to see detail .

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have that edit window as a child of the parent container (containing the grid).

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    //Configuration
});
mainWindow.add(win);
win.show();
```

Then it will come as child to the mainWindow (wont go back). This has one more advantage - whenever you close your mainWindow, this window would also get destroyed with that.

EDITED (Explained in Detail):

You have a grid as

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    //Your configuration
});
```

You must be having it inside some other Window (say mainWindow)

```
var mainWindow = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    items: [grid]
});
```

And here is the new window (edit-window) which you want to open

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    //Configuration
});
```

Hierarchy is:

```
mainWindow
    grid
win
```

Now this `win` is independent of the `mainWindow`. It can go to back and in front of it. And when you click `edit` of grid (in the `mainWindow`), it highlights this and send `win` (edit window) to the back.

I'm asking you to add this `win` as a child to the `mainWindow`:

```
mainWindow.add(win)
```

Then hierarchy would become

```
mainWindow
    grid
    win
```

Now, `win` comes under `mainWindow` and thus can't go behind it. Also, whenever you destroy the `mainWindow` it will destroy all the child items (including `win`).

Comment: i don't get this, Can u please explain briefly or by some example. I am new to extjs.